# show forms on image

Tags: html, image, forms

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/me/images/register.jpg" width="680" height="290">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how can i show `text` and `lables` on this image?

Comment: I have update my answer check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your image as a `background` on either the `td`, `tr` or `table`. If image is not 100% height and width, use `background-position` to position your image where you want it. Then just use html as you would in the table.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zPm2R/